# What formation-keeping software does MMS use?

Tags: nasa, station-keeping, formation-flying

The [Magnetospheric MultiScale (MMS) mission](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/mms/spacecraft/orbit.html) is a NASA mission consisting of four satellites arranged (at apogee) in a tetrahedral formation. [According to this 2015 source](https://phys.org/news/2015-10-nasa-mms-spacecraft-tightest-formation.html):

> On Oct. 15, 2015, a NASA mission broke its own record: the four satellites of its Magnetospheric Multiscale mission are now flying at their smallest separation [~10km], the tightest multi-spacecraft formation ever flown in orbit.

That type of 3-dimensional formation flying is fairly state-of-art (opinion). What software is used by the MMS operations team to maintain the tetrahedral formation in the presence of perturbations? I.e., what software was used for station-keeping? Was a custom solution required or was there an off-the-shelf product suitable to the task?